# How to integrate Bessel function $\int_0^{\infty } J_0(a x) \left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x^3}-\frac{\cos (x)}{x^2}\right) \, dx$

Tags: integration, special-functions

> How to integrate Bessel function $$\int_0^{\infty}J_0(ax)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right)dx.$$ Here $a>1$, $J_0(x)$ is Bessel function.

I try write $J_0(ax)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2}(\frac{ax}{2})^{2k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{iax\cos\theta}d\theta$, but I can not go on.

Comment: May I ask in what context this integral appeared?

Comment: Your integral is the same as $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^\infty x^{-3/2}\,J_0(ax)\,J_{\frac32}(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: This can be recast as a product of Meijer $G$ functions; using the convolution theorem yields the answer $$\begin{cases}\frac{\pi(2-a^2)}{8}&|a|<1\\\frac14\left(\sqrt{a^2-1}+(2-a^2)\operatorname{arccsc}|a|\right)&|a|\ge1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Using the representation of J.M. is not a mathematician, you can apply the first formula of the following link http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/02/02/

Comment: @mickep my friend asked me, I do not know how to do.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Thank you, I will try it.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Thank you for your link, I will see it.